# What are these electrical devices in wall junction boxes?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

My partner purchased a previously poorly-maintained house built in 1924, and these two single-gang boxes have some mystery contents. What are these two receptacles and can they be repurposed as 120V outlets?
I suspect one is a a broken single outlet, as I've measured 120V across the connections, but I have no clue on the other.

[image: first receptacle] [image: second receptacle]

Comment: If they still have power looking like that, then "Danger Will Robertson Danger".  Seems like someone(probably high as a kite) removed the plastic protection/covering from them.  Not something you want to lick.  Turn off power to them now.

Comment: Second one could be a mostly destroyed pushbutton switch. Possibly low voltage, like a doorbell or bell to summon the servants, possibly line voltage. Shut off power and get these things covered with a dead front before restoring power.

Comment: Old time switches were sometimes a Bakelite push button. Saw many back in the day in old manor houses in the Philadelphia suburbs.

Comment: The top one looks like a more modern toggle switch, with most of the insides missing. The bottom is likely an old rotary or push button switch. **N.B.** There are still mains wires (not low-power bell wires) attached to the second device. Use caution -- they might be **live!**

Comment: Further to the comment by @JonCuster, this is an interesting read : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakelite

Comment: It’s time to do research on “knob and tube” wiring. Among other things, insurance companies don’t like it, partly because it’s likely to have been touched by previous occupants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one on the left is an old-school outlet that has been smashed and not repaired.

The one on the right is an old-school switch that has been smashed and not repaired.

Let me guess, when the eviction moratorium expired, the tenant smashed up the place?

Comment: Would that be a rotary switch?

Comment: It's actually an house that was owned by a pretty old individual and fell into disrepair. Is there any particular risk in popping out the old outlet and putting in the new one? I assume that the switch, if that's what it is, can only be removed/covered, and I'm also unsure why there would be a switch there--it's only about a foot off the ground.

Comment: @dmc high risk until you shut off the branch circuit breaker.  A small amount of risk until you shut off the main. (nobody can tell me the branch breaker is enough; I've gotten nailed on a panel **I built** on a circuit **I know** like the back of my hand and that was **definitely off**. It was a freak failure.)  Once you have the "switch" off, you'll be able to see how it's connected.  I would stick a receptacle there by default if it's only 2 wires.

Comment: And by "only two wires" I mean if two wires are connected in a manner that they're also connected *to each other*, then treat them as one wire (i.e. pretend they're pigtailed).